# Should I avoid using px to make react-app mobile friendly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mobile, frontend

What's a good way to make my webapp mobile friendly?  I've been using px mostly however am I supposed to just use vw and vh?  Also, am I supposed to just use @media for the css a million times?

Comment: Percents with breakpoints is a good approach. It gives fluidity to your design, while allowing for varying layouts at different sizes. I’d really look into grid frameworks for mobile friendly design, it’ll help you a lot and make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's good spreadsheet: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Can say from my experience:

1. Use `%` (percents) if you want set size depending on the parent block
2. Use `vw/vh` if you want to set size depending on the screen size
3. Use `rem/em` as usual

Comment: So, basically I should always use vw or vh?

Comment: 1. You will user @media in any cases, because some blocks should be 80% of width on mobile devices and only 65-70% on computers/laptops and so on. 2. I can't say "Use only it", because it's wrong position. % and vw/vh are similar, but they solve things differently. You'll get it only after some amount of tries. Sometimes I ignore both of them and use flex-boxes. As you see, it depends on task.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather broad topic. However, here are some things that may help you out.

`px` isn't bad and has many use-cases. For instance, i tend to use `px` when I'm setting the height of an object. As responsiveness is generally in correlation to width, it get's a bit trickier, but you can use things like `min-width` or `max-width` to start thinking about responsiveness.

You can also uses percentages, however I personally like using css layouts like `flexbox` or `grid` to setup my site. As they tend to be more flexible. So part of the responsive design is already achieved just by using a css layout module.

Generally, there are no hard fast rules in how to make a page responsive, because every website is different. You'll find hundreds of sites giving you `@media` sizes for every kind of screen size known to man, but it's more important to look at your website and see where the content naturally starts to break as it's growing or shrinking. You can then make a more accurate determination as to when you want your `@media` to take effect.

Lastly, you shouldn't need to used `@media` a million times, only where you've decided your layout needs to change. Then just implement your css changes inside of a single `@media` for everything that you want to change at that specific screen size and under or over.